# What do I need to buy to watch HEVC videos on a nine years old TV?

Tags: graphics-cards, hdmi, mini-pc

I have a nine years old TV, a Samsung UE40EH6030W. I can't obviously watch HEVC videos that are all the rage on it. Nor videos using FLAC btw, and probably other "new stuff" as well. What do I have to buy to be able to watch them? Coz converting every video is a massive chore.

The TV has two HDMI ports.

I have a computer that can run these videos just fine but it only has one HDMI port. I really made a mistake by choosing that motherboard. I can switch the cable from my monitor to the TV but it is so cumbersome that I stopped doing it.
My config is AMD Ryzen 5 5600G + TUF Gaming B550-PRO.

My budget is 240€ max if and only if it has added benefits such as extra storage of 512+go. If it's just to be able to play these files, 100-120€ max.

I have two leads:

- a mini PC
- a graphic card

Unfortunately, I know nothing about hardware.
I heard that buying a graphic card with another HDMI port doesn't guarantee that you can play these videos. Is it true?

Anyway, my question is obviously for concrete hardware recommendations. The more, the better. I am even ok with the Raspberry Pi rabbit hole.

PS: if possible, not something sold on amazon, for ethical reasons.